# Java Array loop behaviour

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have been testing some different ways to multiply array items with a constant.

I have produced different results depending on how I loop through the array and I'm having trouble understanding this (I'm fairly new to Java and still getting my head around how things are passed or referenced).

**Test 1**

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4};

for (int number : array)
{
    number *= 2;
}
```

Resulting in array items unmodified:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

It seems like `number` is not the actual array item, but a new `int` that is initialised with it's value. Is that correct?

---

**Test 2**

I thought that by using an array of Objects might work, assuming `number` is then a reference to the actual array item. Here is my test of that using `Integer` instead of `int`:

```
Integer[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4};

for (Integer number : array)
{
    number *= 2;
}
```

Again, resulting in array items unmodified:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

---

**Test 3**

After some head scratching I tried a different loop method, like this:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4};

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++)
{
    array[i] *= 2;
}
```

Resulting in array items multiplied:

```
{2, 4, 6, 8}
```

This final result makes sense to me, but I don't understand the results from the second test (or first for that matter). Until now, I've always assumed the loop used in test 1 and 2 was just a shorthand version of the loop used in test 3, but they are clearly different.

Why isn't this working as I expected? Why are these loops different?

Comment: in third case, you are doing like array[0] = array[0]*2; , i.e you are replacing the array with the new multiplied values.

Comment: Say it with me - Java is pass-by-value. Java is pass-by-value. Java is pass-by-value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because enhanced `for` loop uses a copy of the value in the array. The code in

```
for (int number : array) {
    number *= 2;
}
```

Is similar to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int number = array[i];
    number *= 2;
}
```

Same happens when using `Integer[]`.

Also, when you use enhanced `for` loop in an `Iterable` e.g. `List`, it uses an iterator instead. This means, a code like this:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
intList.add(1);
intList.add(2);
intList.add(3);
intList.add(4);
for(Integer i : intList) {
    i *= 2;
}
```

Is similar to:

```
for(Iterator<Integer> it = intList.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Integer i = it.next();
    i *= 2;
}
```

Related info:

- [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1065197)